# Moving Thunderbird from Windows Seven to Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, windows-7, thunderbird, user-profile

I am trying to move my Thunderbird profile from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 12.04. The simplest explanation of how to do this that I have found so far is at http://www.seoras.com/2008/05/28/how-to-transfer-thunderbird-profile-from-windows-to-ubuntu-804/ I have followed this procedure carefully without difficulty but it does not seem to work. Thunderbird opens fine but has no information in it, no emails, or accounts. It opens just like it did before the profile change. Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try this method: [Migrate your Thunderbird emails from Windows to Linux](http://fosswire.com/post/2008/03/migrate-your-thunderbird-emails-from-windows-to-linux/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this method just now and got exactly the same result. Thunderbird opens fine but has no folders or emails in it. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**1. moving profile from Windows to Ubuntu.**

start TB with profile manager in terminal:

> thunderbird -profilemanager

Then create a new profile. In next screen give a name to the new profile and locate the folder for the profile.

**2. Sharing TB profile (dual boot Win & Ubuntu)**

You can have thunderbird use the same mail directory:

start TB with profile manager in terminal:

> thunderbird -profilemanager

Then create a new profile and add folder as in case 1.

In Account settings, in your local folders, select under message storage the directory where actually the emails are stored. This can be the same in both OSs.

For example, in Windows this would be

> C:/Documents and Settings/user/AppData/Roaming/Thunderbird/Profiles/xyz.default/Mail/Local Folders/

and in Ubuntu, this would be

> /media/A82C58.../Documents and Settings/user/AppData/Roaming/Thunderbird/Profiles/xyz.default/Mail/Local Folders/

Comment: Thanks for the answer Bob. It was helpful because it alerted me to the profile manager. I couldn't get it to work at first but then I started playing around with the settings in profile.ini and got it to work. All is well!

Comment: glad to help :)